# what means build, install and how include?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know:

1.What means build a catkin package?

2.What means install a catkin package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220510/what-means-build,-install-and-how-include?/) by [Hieronix](https://answers.ros.org/users/24981/hieronix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-06**:
This post contains multiple different questions. Please open a new one for different questions, so people can find appropriate answers. It seems 1, 2 and 3, 4 and 5 could be individual posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. This basically compiles the code. There might be additional actions in the cmake file as e.g. downloading patches.
2. This takes the build products and moves them to the install folder dependent on the install rules. WIth catkin you don't necessarily need the install step as you can use the devel folder without installing.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1